# Close MainActivity(main) from another activity (ActivityPoliticas)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, admob

I'm looking for a solution to press the (non-personalized ads) button of the ActivityPolicies and  close the MainActivity and then reopen the MainActivity with the correct ad.

MainActivity(principal)

```
public void politicas(View view) // button
{
    Intent i = new Intent (this, ActivityPolicies.class);
    i.putExtra("valor","politicas");
    startActivity(i);   

}
```

ActivityPolicies

```
public void NonPersonalizedAdvertising(View view) //button
{
    SharedPreferences myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MensajePoliticas.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor =myPreferences.edit();
    myEditor.putString("POLITICAS","LEIDO_NOACEPTADO");
    myEditor.commit();

//Missing some option to close the main activity

*
*
*
 //Reopen the main activity

Intent entrar=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(entrar);


    finish();  // Close the current activity (ActivityPolicies)
}
```

The goal is to close the MainActivity to reload the correct personalized or non-personalized ad. I already have the code but I am missing this option to reload the MainActivity.

Another question:
Close the main activity to reload the ads, can I have problems with some Admob rule?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MainActivity is in backstack, you can call same activity like this:

```
Intent entrar = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
entrar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will open the same MainActivity instance and also give you a new intent.
startActivity(entrar);
```

Now in your MainActivity you can override onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
// here you will get the new Intent. You can reload only the ads programmatically or just call `this.recreate();`
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Only with this part it works for me:

Intent entrar = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
entrar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will open the same MainActivity instance and also give you a new intent.
startActivity(entrar);


-----   Or do I also have to use the onNewIntent part?

Comment: @lina0i0-29 is only required if you need a callback when MainActivity open from ActivityPolicies. If you don't need that. Thats fine too.